# Form that is not hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a table that takes data and displays it, and it works pretty well. However, I have a row in this table that should be hidden and should only be displayed after I press a button, but it is not hidden. What am I doing wrong?

```
<style>
    modificato<?php echo $id;?>{
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script>
    function modificato<?php echo $id;?> {
        document.querySelector("modificato<?php echo $id;?>").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>

<form name="modificato<?php echo $id?>" class="form" method="post" action="" style="display: none;">
    <tr>
        <th>PREMI PER</th>
        <th><input type="submit" name="bottone_modificato<?php echo $id;?>" value="CONFERMARE"></th>
        <th><input type="date" name="data<?php echo $id;?>" value='<?php echo $data?>'></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="nome<?php echo $id;?>" size="10" maxlength="<?php echo $LENGTH_NOME;?>" value="<?php echo $nome;?>"></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="valore<?php echo $id;?>" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 46 && event.charCode <= 57' size="6" maxlength="<?php echo $LENGTH_PREZZO;?>" value="<?php echo $valore;?>"></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="chilometri<?php echo $id;?>" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 46 && event.charCode <= 57' size="6" maxlength="<?php echo $LENGTH_CHILOMETRI;?>" value="<?php echo $chilometri;?>"></th>
        <th><textarea name="note<?php echo $id;?>" rows="3" cols="20" maxlength="250"><?php echo $note;?></textarea></th>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Comment: I've tried `display: none` inside form  inside <style> tags but nothing

Comment: SyntaxError. Open console, read the error, then google the error. And here we go - solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks, like problem is in your styles.

```
modificato<?php echo $id;?>
```

will look for an element modificato (for example, modificato123).

But, as I understand, you need to hide a form. Then your style can look like

```
form[name=modificato<?php echo $id;?>] {
    display: none;
}
```

Or:

```
.form {
    display: none;
}
```

Or:

```
#some-element-id {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the elements aren't hide as u can see here http://www.onerentsrl.it/gestione-veicolo.php?id=102

Comment: as PHP i know how to solve it easy, but i prefer that it works user side and not server side

Comment: First of all you have a JS error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`. You forgot about braces. Cannot be `function modificato11 {`, must be `function modificato11() {`

Comment: Secondly, as I see in Chrome inspector, your form in really not visible. However, your form closes at once after it is opened. You have an error in HTML code. That is why your inputs and textarea are visible: they are just outside the invisible form.

Comment: I suggest you to hide a `tr` element, not `form`.

Comment: thanks, now the row is hide, i'm not a lot practicle of JS and CSS, then is like write in portuguese when u know just spanish, anyway +1 for you. Now i have just to work why JS function doesn't unhide element ahahah, but i'm positive that I can solve it :D